# Matplotlib: make more than one selection using Polygon Selector

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to use PolygonSelector to select multiple areas, like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/focvQ.png)

How should I modify the example Polygon Selector code [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/widgets/polygon_selector_demo.html) ? Currently, it only allows to make one selection.

Comment: Loop over the selection process and collect the intermediate results (list, array, dictionary of your choice) until a stop condition defined by you (n selections, stop button) is fulfilled. What else can be said in response to such a broad question?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.